# Datagrid with ListCollectionView - how to apply filter on all properties without memory leak?

Tags: wpf, listcollectionview

My Datagrid should be filtered by all columns. For that I have a TextBox in my View. So whatever text is being written, Datagrid should filter by it.

I have more questions:

1. How to apply filter on all columns, based on text?
2. I tried filtering only one column, but filtering is very slow (aprox. 37.000 items). How can I speed up filtering?
3. Filtering (tested on one column) produces huge memory leak. Any way to fix this?

**Properties for binding:**

```
public ListCollectionView AllData
{
   get { return _alldata; }
   set { _alldata = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
private ListCollectionView _alldata;

public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Data
{
   get { return _data; }
   set { _data = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _data;
```

**Method to get all data (binding):**

```
private async Task Get_Contracts()
{
   Data = await GetData();
        
   AllData = new ListCollectionView(Data);
}
```

**Filtering method:**

```
private void ApplyFilter(bool search_by_text)
{
   try
   {
      if (search_by_text)
      {
         //??  
         AllData.Filter = (e) => {};
    
         //This works - a new Collection created instead of filtering existing one
         //var filter = Data.Where(p => p.GetType().GetProperties().Any(a =>
                         a.GetValue(p, null) != null && a.GetValue(p, null).ToString().ToUpper().Contains(Search_text.ToUpper()))).ToObservableCollection();

         //Data = new ListCollectionView(filter)
       }
       else
       {
         //Filter works, but very slowly with memory leak
         Data.Filter = delegate (object item)
         {    
            if (!(item is DataModel data))
            {
               return false;
            }
    
             return (Selected_Name != null ? data.NAME == "Lucy" : true);
    
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Use two collections. One that contains all unfiltered items and one that contains the filtered ones and then you add and remove items from the latter.

Comment: @mm8, I allready have that half done. So you think I should stick with this instead of filtering just with ListCollectionView ?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't use the `Filter` property of the `CollectionView` if performance is an issue.

Comment: Where are those 37k items coming from? You shouldn't display 37k items in the first place. This is not clever design. No user will ever scroll through and view 37k items. When you allow the user to use smart filters *before* you display any items you should be able to reduce the item count drastically. Less items means faster sorting or filtering. I assume that you retrieve this amount of data from a database. In this case use the highly optimized filter functionality of the database. It will be faster by a magnitude.

Comment: Then the main question is, why do think you have created a memory leak? Or do you confuse memory allocation with a memory leak (which is allocated memory that is not freed until the lifetime of the application ends?

Comment: @BionicCode,yes,data comes from database. Unfortunally, this app needs to display at least total items count. About displaying all of them I agree, but they actually do scroll down and need sorting on all items. Do you have any links with examples you were talking?

Comment: The correct UI design or design flow would be **1)** If you need to display data initially, load the data, count the rows (data sets) and partition it into pages. Otherwise start with a blank data view and ask the user to populate it by defining filters or by providing a search query.

Comment: **2)** Do not load all data, but load the first e.g. 2 pages. A page of data sets maps to a page in the data view.  At this point you can show the user a total record count and a page index. This means, the user can only scroll through about 100 items before he must change the page (or you change it for him implicitly).

Comment: **3)** When the user steps through the pages you fetch more data to populate the forward cache in the background. You can create all pages in the background after you have initialized the data view with the initial two pages to improve loading times. But note that in case the user is likely to filter or start a search frequently it doesn't make sense to load all data in the background. Don't waste memory and CPU/IO resources.

Comment: **4)** When the user starts a search of filters data, delegate this data operation to the database for maximum performance (and to relief the UI - and in case the application uses a remote database we relief the client machine from work stress too). **5)** Once you retrieved the result from the database restart the flow from *2)*. You may improve the flow by checking the result size (data set count). If it doesn't exceed e.g. 100 items, you can sort and filter using the `CollectionView`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no links. Just google "data virtualization" or "UI data partitioning". You can even search for UX design guidelines for big data sets. Maybe you can refer to some examples e.g. sports statistics or gaming statistics or leader boards. Any application that displays big data usually uses data virtualization, data paging and view paging. Because database servers are usually high performance and the database itself is highly optimized to execute search queries, sorting and filtering is usually delegated to the database.

Comment: You must always expect the client machine to be from 1980. Filtering 37k items could be acceptable slow on your high end developer machine but painfully slow on the client machine. Offload as much performance intensive load to external services that you can control in order to ensure the optimal performance.

Comment: @BionicCode, thanks for brief explanation, I'll take a look at this things. However, my initial problem are our users. I work in government, dealing with payment system, bank transactions etc. Our users widely needs apps for monthly, quaterly, yearly reports, exports, data checking etc. It is not unusual for our apps to display search result over 1 million rows. And almost every time I get demand for sorting data on all records. So I'm stuck between user demands and my suggestions - which almost never prevail. My boss doesn't seem to care either :(

Comment: I've done filtering as mm8 suggested, works much better than ListCollectionView. Filtering is almost instant, aprox. 1 second for string comparison on every column (15 columns, 37k items). But I will investigate option for creating custom WPF Datagrid that would support pagination and, more importantly, allowing to sort columns on all data, not just currently displayed data (that will be shot in head, I know). Anyway, thank you both for giving me a guidelines.

Comment: The question is: how many of the "over 1 million rows" can the user view? Maybe 10? Max 20? The user is looking for particular entries, maybe by alphabet, I don't know. Which user will scroll through 1 million rows??? None. They want to use a search. You must offer different types of filters: a) by alphabet/number: show a drop down that contains the letters of the alphabet b) by content: allow the user to enter a string that the records must contain c) expression based search: allow the user to use logical expressions like "where column Value = 1000 AND column "Name" = "mike".

Comment: When displaying potential 37k - 1M data sets you definitely need a powerful search filter. Don't let the user hang with sorting and endless scrolling. Regarding your idea of a custom DataGrid, I don't think that this is necessary. You must differentiate between UI paging and data paging where both can match. For example, page data by 30 entries. Page view to show a full data page. You can have horizontal UI paging (like a book), where the user clicks on a next button to load the new page that contains a DataGrid that contains a data page (e.g. 30 items).

Comment: The UI page is abstract. You basically reuse the same DataGrid and just load the new page data and advance the page indicator in the UI. Alternatively, you can have vertical paging, where the user can scroll infinitely and you load pages while scrolling. Horizontal pages are significantly easier to implement. The data paging must take place in the View Model and not the View. that's why you don't have to create a custom DataGrid. I can only recommend to delegate filtering to the database. Just use SQL queries to obtain the filtered data set.

Comment: @BionicCode I allready have implemented one app with paging, but as I said bottom problem is that our users usually wish to sort based on all data. I don't know why they insist that so much, but that's how It is. We deal with big data everyday, although mostly is important only total number and different kind of sums.